# How to avoid the space between two sections

Tags: html, css

[image]
When I view my web on full size, it will show like the left image.
When I narrow the window, it will display like the right image

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 max-height: 1200px;
}
body {
    max-height: 1200px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 color: rgba(88,88,88,0.92);
}
#bgimg{
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 864px;
}
.bgimg{
 background: url(sideimage_4.png) no-repeat  center ;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 1100px;
 margin: 0;
 
}
.goleft{
 float: left;
}
#sideright{
 width: 60%;
 float: right;
 background-color:white;
 height: 1100px;
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin-left: auto;
}
#intro{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: white;
}
#introinner{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10% 10px;
}
#introinner h1{
 font-family: 'Sofia';
 font-size: 500%;
 font-weight: 800;
}
#introinner p{
 margin: 8px;
 font-family: 'Sofia';
 
}
#introinner a i{
 font-size: 80%;
 color: rgba(88,88,88,0.92);
}
#banner{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#banner img{
 width: 100%;
}
#cf {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
 width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
#selfintro{
 margin-top: 500px;
 clear: top;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/homecss.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <nav id="bgimg" class="goleft">
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
 </nav>
 <section id="sideright" class="goleft">
  <section id="intro">
   <div id="introinner">
    <h1>Troy Wu</h1>
    <p>The King in the South</p>
    <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" download="meizi" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download">DownLoad My Pic</i></a>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section id="banner">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </section>
  <div id="cf">
   <img class="bottom" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
   <img class="top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150">
  </div>
  <div id="selfintro"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  <p>asdfasdf asd</p>
  
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

I post my code for these two sections. I am pretty sure that the issue happens on the div (cf), because of the position:relative and absolute. I tried to put a margin-top on the css, but it doesn't work. I've been trying to solve this for two days, and still have not clue to this. can you help me solve this issue? how to avoid the space between these two sections?

Comment: Please add your code properly.

Comment: Would you be able to explain better what you are trying to achieve. There might be some better options to solve your problem.

Comment: hi guys. i uploaded my entire code already. I don't how to upload my original images. I think you can just simply replace the image path with yours will work. I am trying to make the web scale properly, but when I view it in full-size screen, the top photo will cover the bottom photo. and when I narrow the screen, there is gap between top image and bottom image. As you see on the photo I uploaded. I guess you will know what I mean if you can replace the src path with your local image. please let me know if there is still some words confuse u

Comment: Use https://placeholder.com/ to mock images.

Comment: You should have a look at CSS flexbox for positioning. It's really cool and easy to use. I'd give you an example but I'm not at my computer right now.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding in position property: relative & absolute. I read the explanation w3schools.com  a lot, but I am still confused about this. if I do not add the position property on css, the page will display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is usually caused by the elements being inline-block elements instead of block elements, and as inline-block elements respect the whitespace in the markup, you get these gaps between elements.

You can reduce the font-size to zero, and as the space is dependent on the font size, that can solve the problem, or you can remove all the whitespace in your markup (which makes for messy HTML), or you can make the offending elements block items instead of inline-block items if that does't break your layout.

As I don't see any text on your layouts, I would set the font size to zero and see if that solves it, and then set the font size specifically on spans or divs containing text if you need to add labels or titles etc.